# By Passing J_security_check

Tags: java, apache, authentication, j-security-check

I am trying to add new functionality to a formerly built web application. The application uses `j_security_check` . I want to use another single-sign-on service to log in to the application. What is the best practice for that?

P.S. I can't see where `j_security_check` checks for the user name and password. Any help with that will be appreciated.

Edit: actually what i want to do is to use another sso service to login to j_security_check.  the other SSO System is another we application. user logins to that application and that application post me a token. After it posts me the token I can get the user id of logged in person.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find "j\_security\_check"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723138/where-can-i-find-j-security-check)

Comment: *"What is the best practice for that?"* - There is no such thing as best practice for using "another" SSO system.  You pick the SSO system that meets your requirements ... and then you implement it.  And if you are really asking for a recommendation, that's not what SO Questions are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`j_security_check` or `Realm` is a way that web container or `tomcat` check the login itself!
If you check the `server.xml` in configuration files of `tomcat` or `context.xml` in your `META-INF` files, you can see the `Realm` tag which shows how the `Realm` check the login functionality.

You cannot use `Realm` for more than one times in an application. if you want to implement another single sign on, you should implement it yourself. But I don't know why you want to implement two single sign on! it is really strange!

The best way I think is putting somethings in `session` and check it to make sure that user is logging in.

As you said that there are too many pages and handling this kind of projects is really hard, I suggest you to use `Front Controller` pattern or `Facade` Design pattern. You can check the session only in `Front Controller`.
You can read more here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern

http://java.dzone.com/articles/understanding-front-controller
http://www.allapplabs.com/j2ee_design_patterns/j2ee_design_patterns_front_controller.htm

Comment: Thanks for your answer at first. the system is like this: user logins to another web application. this application posts me a token. I can get user information by using this token and a web service. After I get the token I want to make user login to j_security_check as well. there are hundreds of pages in the application. in every page it checks for the context for logged in users. if I dont do it this way i have to change every single page . I am trying to figure out the solution which requires the less afford.

Comment: What is the relation between the application that user should login into it and your application? Both of them are in a same web application?

Comment: No they are totally seperate. Its a nationally wide service that enables citizens to login to some govermental services with their national id number . after login my application can retrieve some other citizenship information as well. this make us use and always updated information database about our users. and if we can manage we dont need to create a users database from scratch.

Comment: In such these applications, most of them put somethings in session. I suggest you to check the session information to understand that is the user login into system or not. hmmm? What's your opinion?

Comment: actually i am trying to do it in that way. there is another one page application. I managed to integrate the new sso in there. and deleted the j-security_check. but in this application what i am trying to do is after user logged in make same login in j_security_check system on background.

Comment: As I said you should put somethings in session and use it for authentication!

Comment: i can do it . but as i said there are hundreds of pages. i should update all pages to do it in that way.

Comment: I just edit my answer. Please refer to it and you got your answer please select it as accepted answer!

Comment: Hi. i could manage to login using url paramaters.what i was missing was there was another parameter mypw. it was used to check the captcha. I made a fixed captcha and passed the value of it as well. final login url link was something like that mydomain.com/j_security_check?j_password=userPassword&j_username=username&mypw=aaa      where aaaa is the fixed captcha value.